# web api project not working on webhost after publish

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, publish

i am trying to publish my API on my web hosting service using PLESK and i DO the following thing below :

1. Publish The Solution on visual Studio
2. Zip The Publish folder
3. Upload on my host
4. check the connection string and web config file
5. check the database to ensure be created
6. enter the url of host and /swagger(i use that for my api) and nothing works
   not even the single line of error

Comment: You can enable logging in web.config file to get more detail about errors:
[https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1487/enabling-asp_net-core-error-logging.aspx](Enabling ASP.NET Core Error Logging)

Comment: Did you try to publish it  at your local IIS at first?

Comment: @Sergey yes it works on localhost but but it does not work on my hosting service

Comment: @HamedNaeemaei i did it but there is no file created by application  on log folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, after deployment open your web.config on the host and set stdoutLogEnabled="true".

Create a "logs" folder nearby and grant permissions to write to this folder from IIS worker account (Either "IIS AppPool\YourApplicationPoolName" or IUSR depending on your server config). Alternatively you can set stdoutLogFile to somewhere else.

After this restart the web site and you will get a log files with any startup error that is happening here. Most often cases are lack of appsettings.Production.json with all necessary configs or lack of database access, etc.

Comment: i do not have access to my iis profile and it just a plesk account

Comment: any logs on a portal? Websites and Domains > Logs

Answer (score 0):

finally i solve the problem by test it on local with the same dll exported to webhost and enable logs for it .
it shows the error

> the error was the xml file who created on debug folder nor release and
> i copy that to release and boom! it works!